# Numerical Hodge decomposition with boundaries

Tags: numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

For a fluid simulation, I'm using the algorithm proposed by Jos Stam (http://www.intpowertechcorp.com/GDC03.pdf).

One step of the algorithm is a routine that projects the velocity vector field so that it becomes an incompressible field (`div F = 0`). To achieve that, it uses the Hodge decomposition to decompose the field into the sum an incompressible field (`div F = 0`) and a gradient field (`curl F = 0`).

Now we'd like to introduce boundaries that act like walls in the fluid. The fluid on one side of the wall must not influence the fluid on the other side.

[image]

This is achieved easily in the `advect()`, `setBnd()` and `diffuse()` steps of the solver. However, I'm not sure how to introduce this boundary separation in the `project()` step. My first approach was to just cut all the influences of those 'cell neighbors' that are on the other side of the boundary (see image above: the orange arrows represent neighbour cells across the boundary).

But this leads to an unstable solution. The fluid begins to move across the boundary without any force present.

**Is there an easy solution to this problem?**

Here's the code of the `project()` routine from Jos Stam's paper:

```
void project ( int N, float * u, float * v, float * p, float * div )
{
    int i, j, k;
    float h;
    h = 1.0/N;

    // calculate div
    for ( i=1 ; i<=N ; i++ ) {
        for ( j=1 ; j<=N ; j++ ) {
            div[IX(i,j)] = -0.5*h*(
                u[IX(i+1,j)]-u[IX(i-1,j)]+
                v[IX(i,j+1)]-v[IX(i,j-1)]);
            p[IX(i,j)] = 0;
        }
    }

    // set boundaries
    set_bnd ( N, 0, div ); set_bnd ( N, 0, p );

    // solve linear equation system using Gauss Seidel
    for ( k=0 ; k<20 ; k++ ) {
        for ( i=1 ; i<=N ; i++ ) {
            for ( j=1 ; j<=N ; j++ ) {
                p[IX(i,j)] = (div[IX(i,j)]+
                    p[IX(i-1,j)]+p[IX(i+1,j)]+
                    p[IX(i,j-1)]+p[IX(i,j+1)])/4;
            }
        }
        set_bnd ( N, 0, p );
    }

    // subtract the gradient field from our vector field ==> result has zero divergence
    for ( i=1 ; i<=N ; i++ ) {
        for ( j=1 ; j<=N ; j++ ) {
            u[IX(i,j)] -= 0.5*(p[IX(i+1,j)]-p[IX(i-1,j)])/h;
            v[IX(i,j)] -= 0.5*(p[IX(i,j+1)]-p[IX(i,j-1)])/h;
        }
    }
    set_bnd ( N, 1, u ); set_bnd ( N, 2, v );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using the following approach, which works great. It also seems to make some sense:

- First, mark the 'arrows' which cross a boundary. In the image above, they are the orange arrows.
- In the `calculate div` step of the code, check which arrows are orange. For all 'orange neighbours', replace their values (for example `u[IX(i+1,j)]` for the right neighbour) by the respective value of the cell itself (for example `u[IX(i,j)]`).
- In the `solve linear equation` step, remove the values of the 'orange neighbours' from the inner sum, and set the divisor to `4 minus the number of orange neighbours`.
- In the `subtract gradient field` step, do the same as in the `calculate div` step: Replace the neighbour values by the value of the cell itself, if the neighbour is across the boundary.